# magit + ido: do not offer tags in completing read?

Tags: magit, ido

**Q:** how can I get `magit` + `ido` to ignore tags when checking out a branch?

I'm using `magit` + `ido`.  When I go to check out a branch, `ido`
helpfully gives me the names of all existing branches, but it also
gives me the names of all tags.  Sometimes I want that, but
usually I don't.

How can I convince `magit` + `ido` *not* to offer tags as a completion option?

Answer (score 1):

You can control how refs are sorted with `magit-list-refs-sortby`, but
Magit doesn't have a built-in option for excluding tags from the
candidates listed by `magit-checkout`.

One way you could get this behavior is by overriding
`magit-checkout`'s interactive form, temporarily removing "refs/tags"
from `magit-list-refs-namespaces`.

```
(advice-add
 'magit-checkout :around
 (lambda (f revision)
   (interactive
    (list (let ((magit-list-refs-namespaces
                 (remove "refs/tags" magit-list-refs-namespaces)))
            (magit-read-other-branch-or-commit "Checkout"))))
   (funcall f revision))
 '((name . "magit-checkout-notags")))
```